# Bottom Bar not visible when scroll to top of the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css, bottomnavigationview

I have a React component for a bottom bar that should toggle its visibility based on the scroll direction and position. Despite setting the scroll to 0, the bottom bar doesn't consistently appear on mobile devices when scrolling up or at the top of the page.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {
  BsHeartFill,
  BsFillPersonFill,
  BsFillBasket2Fill,
  BsCart2,
} from 'react-icons/bs';
import { Link, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import { AiFillHome } from 'react-icons/ai';
import { IoIosCube } from 'react-icons/io';
import CategorySVG from './SVGS/CategorySVG';
import useUser from './hooks/useUser';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { success } from '../common/Common.Action';

export default function BottomBar({
  data,
  onMoveWhishListItem,
  handleClick,
  addCart,
  foundCartProduct,
  itemChecked,
  addProductToCart,
  handleCheckout,
  buyProduct,
}) {
  const [scrollDirection, setScrollDirection] = useState('up');
  const [bottomBarVisible, setBottomBarVisible] = useState(true);
  const { isAuthenticated } = useUser();
  const location = useLocation();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const productDetailsSlug = location.pathname.includes('product-details');

  useEffect(() => {
    let prevScrollY = window.scrollY;

    const handleScroll = () => {
      const currentScrollY = window.scrollY;

      if (currentScrollY > prevScrollY) {
        setScrollDirection('down');
      } else {
        setScrollDirection('up');
      }

      if (scrollDirection === 'down') {
        setBottomBarVisible(false);
      } else if (currentScrollY === 0) {
        setBottomBarVisible(true);
      } else {
        setBottomBarVisible(true);
      }

      prevScrollY = currentScrollY;
    };

    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    };
  }, [scrollDirection]);

  return (
    <>
      {!productDetailsSlug ? (
        <div
          className={`bg-white h-16 z-20 text-gray-700 fixed bottom-0 left-0 right-0 max-w-screen md:hidden flex justify-center items-center ${
            !bottomBarVisible ? 'bottom-bar hidden' : ''
          }`}
        >
          <div className="flex justify-between items-center w-full px-4">
            <Link
              to="/"
              className={`flex flex-col items-center ${
                location.pathname === '/' ? 'text-[#ec6525]' : ''
              }`}
            >
              <AiFillHome size={25} />
              <p className="text-[12px] font-medium">Home</p>
            </Link>
            <Link
              className={`flex flex-col items-center ${
                location.pathname === '/all-category' ? 'text-[#ec6525]' : ''
              }`}
              to="/all-category"
            >
              <CategorySVG />
              <p className="text-[12px] font-medium">Categories</p>
            </Link>
            {!isAuthenticated ? (
              <Link
                to="/login"
                className={`flex flex-col items-center ${
                  location.pathname === '/login' ? 'text-[#ec6525]' : ''
                }`}
                state={{ prev: '/' }}
              >
                <BsFillPersonFill size={25} />
                <p className="text-[12px] font-medium">Account</p>
              </Link>
            ) : (
              <Link
                to="/account"
                className={`flex flex-col items-center ${
                  location.pathname === '/account' ? 'text-[#ec6525]' : ''
                }`}
              >
                <BsFillPersonFill size={25} />
                <p className="text-[12px] font-medium">Account</p>
              </Link>
            )}

            {isAuthenticated && (
              <>
                <Link
                  to="/wishlist"
                  className={`flex flex-col items-center ${
                    location.pathname === '/wishlist' ? 'text-[#ec6525]' : ''
                  }`}
                >
                  <BsHeartFill size={25} />
                  <p className="text-[12px] font-medium">Wishlist</p>
                </Link>

                <Link
                  to="/order-history"
                  className={`flex flex-col items-center ${
                    location.pathname === '/order-history'
                      ? 'text-[#ec6525]'
                      : ''
                  }`}
                >
                  <IoIosCube size={25} />
                  <p className="text-[12px] font-medium">Orders</p>
                </Link>
              </>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <ul className="bg-white h-16 z-20 text-gray-700 fixed bottom-0 left-0 right-0 max-w-screen md:hidden flex gap-2 justify-around items-center">
          <li onClick={() => onMoveWhishListItem(data)}>
            {!isAuthenticated ? (
              <button
                className="border border-gray-300 px-4 py-3 rounded-lg"
                onClick={handleClick}
              >
                <BsHeartFill className="text-gray-600" size={20} />
              </button>
            ) : (
              <button className="border border-gray-300 px-4 py-3 rounded-lg">
                {data?.isFavorite ? (
                  <BsHeartFill className="text-pink-500" size={20} />
                ) : (
                  <BsHeartFill className="text-gray-600" size={20} />
                )}
              </button>
            )}
          </li>
          <li className="w-40">
            {addCart === false && !foundCartProduct ? (
              <button
                onClick={() => {
                  if (itemChecked) {
                    addProductToCart(data);
                  } else {
                    dispatch(success('Select Variant First'));
                  }
                }}
                className="bg-[#FF9F00] w-full text-white font-medium px-2 py-3 rounded-lg flex items-center justify-center gap-1"
              >
                <BsFillBasket2Fill />
                Add To Cart
              </button>
            ) : (
              <Link
                to="/cart"
                className="bg-[#FF9F00] w-full text-white font-medium px-2 py-3 rounded-lg flex items-center justify-center gap-1"
              >
                <BsFillBasket2Fill />
                GO TO CART
              </Link>
            )}
          </li>
          <li className="w-40">
            {isAuthenticated && data?.stock > 0 ? (
              <button
                className="bg-[#FB641B] flex items-center justify-center w-full text-white font-medium px-2 py-3 rounded-lg gap-1"
                onClick={() => {
                  if (itemChecked) {
                    buyProduct(data);
                  } else {
                    dispatch(success('Select Variant First'));
                  }
                }}
              >
                <BsCart2 />
                BUY NOW
              </button>
            ) : (
              <button
                className="bg-[#FB641B] flex items-center justify-center w-full text-white font-medium px-2 py-3 rounded-lg gap-1"
                onClick={handleCheckout}
              >
                <BsCart2 />
                BUY NOW
              </button>
            )}
          </li>
        </ul>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

When testing on real mobile devices, the bottom bar doesn't consistently appear, although the logic is set to display it when scrolling up or at the top of the page. It seems the visibility toggling is not working as expected, and the bottom bar remains hidden on mobile devices despite setting the scroll to 0.

I would appreciate guidance or suggestions on how to ensure that the bottom bar shows as intended on mobile devices when the scroll is at the top or scrolling up, according to the logic implemented in the useEffect for handleScroll.

If anyone has encountered a similar issue or has insight into handling scroll events in React for mobile devices, your input or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a big fan of tapping into scroll events and do manual calculations. It is always error prone and for this reason modern browsers offer a new API for dealing with this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Have a look at the examples there and also check out [this npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-intersection-observer) for React.